# AWS appsync query performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

i have the problem that my query is kinda slow. This is my issue:

I have Groups and Users. In a Group there can be many users. I store the user Id in

```
type Group @model {
  id: ID!
  userIds: [ID]
}
```

And here the user:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID
}
```

Now i have a query where i search every user that is in the group like this:

```
queryGroups({
    filter: {
          userIds: {
            contains: "userId",
          },
    },
  })
```

`userIds` can contain up to 10k entries and there can be many Groups. How do i increase the query speed?

Is there a better to solution to structure this?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike an rdb you should include whole types in relations rather than just IDs. Also references can be bidirectional.

```
type Group @model {
  id: ID!
  users: [User]
}

type User @model {
  id: ID
  groups: [Group]
}
```

You may find [my post on GraphQL for SQL developers](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-1)  helpful in developing your model.